# Wrong result when comparing ref and WeakMethod in Python?

Tags: python, weak-references

I'm using a `set` to hold weak references to callables. These can be functions, callable instances (i.e. using the `__call__` method), and bound methods. Following the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#module-weakref), I'm using `weakref.WeakMethod` for bound methods, and `weakref.ref` for other callables.

The issue I'm facing, is best explained by an example:

```
from weakref import ref, WeakMethod

class Callbacks:
    def method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('method()')

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__call__()')


cb = Callbacks()
listeners = set()

listeners.add(ref(cb))
print(f'#listeners: expected = 1, actual = {len(listeners)}')

listeners.add(WeakMethod(cb.method))
print(f'#listeners: expected = 2, actual = {len(listeners)}')
```

This prints:

> #listeners: expected = 1, actual = 1 
> #listeners: expected = 2, actual = 1

Digging in, I see that indeed `WeakMethod(cb.method) == ref(cb)`, even though `cb.method != cb`. What am I missing?

Comment: Cannot reproduce; all 4 tests pass when I execute `python3 -munittest tmp.py` (with the above being the contents of `tmp.py`).

Comment: Given that the code under test doesn't use weak references at all, it's not clear that you are testing anything useful, other than the `weakref` module itself.

Comment: @chepner rephrased so both the issue and the motivations are (hopefully) clear.

Comment: OK, yes, that's clearer, and yes, that does seem odd to me. The documentation mentions that `WeakMethod` only *simulates* a reference to the bound method, so perhaps it really is just a weak reference to the object and "reconstructs" a weak reference to the bound method later. (Note that `cb.method` creates a *new* `method` instance each time it is used; it's not just an expression that references a long-lived object like `cb` does.)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are aware that the expression `cb.method` creates a *new* instance of the class `method` each time it is evaluated; it's not just a reference to some long-lived object.

```
>>> x = cb.method
>>> y = cb.method
>>> x is y
False
```

Second, `WeakMethod` is a subclass of `ref`, so it really is just a reference to the original object, *but* with additional information about the method allowing it to reconstitute a bound method on demand.

The documentation for `WeakMethod` goes into more detail about why it is necessary, rather than just using `ref(cb.method)`.

Third, `WeakMethod.__hash__` is just set equal to `ref.__hash__`, so hashing a `WeakMethod` doesn't use any of that extra information. As far as the hash value is concerned, any `WeakMethod` involving `cb` is equivalent to a weak reference to `cb` itself.

This suggests you are going to have to adapt your code to how weak references behave.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. To me it seems a quirk in `WeakMethod`: even though `id(x) != id(y)`,  both `x == y`  and `WeakMethod(x) == WeakMethod(y)` are true, which makes sense. However, altough `cb != cb.method`m we still get `ref(cb) == WeakMethod(cb.method)`. 
Since sets use `__eq__` to compare objects, my 2nd call does not add the callable to the set. Obviously, I'll change my code to account for this.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if there's a deeper reason *why* `WeakMethod.__hash__` is set to `rep.__hash__`, rather than making a definition that takes the specific method into account.

Answer (score 0):

So, the matter is that both the hash and `__eq__` for `WeakMethod` are equal what is returned for `weakref.ref()` of the same instance from which you created the `WeakMethod`. Which means that despite being different objects, both weakreferences are "one same thing" as long as an ordinary set is concerned. The extra data on the WeakMethod will return you a bound method when it is called - but both the `ref` and `WeakMethod` objects are weak-references to the same instance - and will start returning `None` as soon as the original instance has no hard-references left.

The side effect of this is what you found out: in a set, or in a dictionary, you can only have *one* of a weak reference to an instance, or a weak reference to any of its methods as an element or key.

Look on the iPython snippet bellow as just the first of (ref, WeakMethod) to the same instance is kept when added to a set:

```
In [101]: class A:
     ...:     def b(self):
     ...:         print("b")
     ...: 

In [102]: instance = [A()]  # not assigning directly to the variable, as ipython creates other r
     ...: eferences to it, and it becomes hard to test the weakreferences

In [103]: r1 = weakref.ref(instance[0])

In [104]: r2 = weakref.WeakMethod(instance[0].b)

In [105]: r1().b()
b

In [106]: r2().b()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[106], line 1
----> 1 r2().b()

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'b'

In [107]: r2()()
b

In [108]: r1 is r2
Out[108]: False

In [109]: hash(r1) == hash(r2), r1 == r2
Out[109]: (True, True)

In [110]: b = set()

In [111]: b.add(r1)

In [112]: b
Out[112]: {<weakref at 0x7fda574df5b0; to 'A' at 0x7fda576d2c10>}

In [113]: b.add(r2)

In [114]: b
Out[114]: {<weakref at 0x7fda574df5b0; to 'A' at 0x7fda576d2c10>}

In [115]: c = set()

In [116]: c.add(r2)

In [117]: c
Out[117]: {<weakref at 0x7fda565233e0; to 'A' at 0x7fda576d2c10>}

In [118]: c.add(r1)

In [119]: c
Out[119]: {<weakref at 0x7fda565233e0; to 'A' at 0x7fda576d2c10>}

In [120]: next(iter(c))()
Out[120]: <bound method A.b of <__main__.A object at 0x7fda576d2c10>>

In [121]: next(iter(c))()()
b

In [122]: next(iter(b))().b()
b
```

In "real world" terms both using `ref` and `WeakMethods` are a bit low level, and you'd be better using a `weakref.WeakSet`
or a `weakref.WeakKeyDictionary` to hold your weak-references - it is much more practical, as you don't have to first make a call to retrieve a hard-reference, then test if the result of the call is not None, and then consume your object: using a `WeakSet` allows you to simply consume your items each time you need to iterate over the objects you hold a weak reference to.